# Restrict content area height for print

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a print CSS which allows me to restrict the height of the content of articles on my site. I would like to place a full-width bar across the bottom of each print page using `position:fixed;` but in order for this to work, I also need to restrict the height of the article content area so that the bar does not cover any of the content on each page. Here's what I have tried so far, but the height does not seem to be restricted:

```css
.print-footer {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
 .print-footer img {
  max-width:100%;
 }

@media print {
  .article-content {
    height:80%;
   }
  .print-footer {
    display:block;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="article-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae posuere felis. Fusce euismod quam sit amet sodales maximus. Cras eget scelerisque augue. Proin a tincidunt nisl, vitae lacinia lectus. Vivamus tincidunt felis eget facilisis tristique. Nullam facilisis, eros quis hendrerit hendrerit, purus nisi congue libero, sit amet facilisis ligula sapien sit amet augue. Integer ac nulla nisl. Suspendisse sed eros quis est interdum ultricies. Donec tincidunt libero lacus, sed laoreet quam rutrum eget. Morbi vitae ullamcorper erat. Phasellus eu purus eget ante congue blandit ac ac ipsum.</p>

<p>Mauris neque ligula, dictum a nibh ut, volutpat ullamcorper urna. In ullamcorper tortor sit amet pellentesque iaculis. Mauris sagittis eleifend scelerisque. Vestibulum volutpat euismod turpis, gravida tempus liguala ultricies vulputate. Maecenas odio sem, pulvinar eget vulputate nec, dictum mollis neque. Aliquam porttitor mi eu scelerisque varius. Etiam vel eros mattis, luctus diam ac, pretium ligula. Maecenas placerat posuere turpis, id convallis augue efficitur porttitor. Fusce tempor tempor convallis.</p>

Quisque imperdiet a dui sed maximus. Nulla sollicitudin fermentum est nec interdum. Nulla consectetur tempus purus, id lobortis neque molestie elementum. Praesent pharetra convallis tincidunt. Proin pellentesque placerat libero vitae pretium. Aenean sodales fringilla ipsum, id suscipit leo. Aliquam sit amet ornare nulla. Quisque sem nisi, auctor facilisis arcu varius, tristique maximus ligula. Nulla imperdiet nunc ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque magna lacus, elementum non sem eget, posuere blandit nunc. Morbi nec arcu vitae odio consequat consectetur. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

<p>Nulla facilisi. Duis pretium blandit elit, a facilisis ipsum finibus sed. Pellentesque semper molestie consectetur. Vivamus sit amet enim ac quam commodo vulputate a pretium nibh. Sed commodo posuere metus, nec mattis arcu lobortis vel. Praesent finibus maximus vestibulum. Sed ultrices urna et pulvinar elementum. Pellentesque lacinia lorem sit amet lectus tempus, ut pharetra nisi tincidunt. Ut sit amet convallis odio. Nam ut massa nisi. Donec ac laoreet mi. Duis quis elementum sapien, at tempor odio. Sed tempus urna ac venenatis commodo. Suspendisse bibendum tortor sit amet risus convallis, gravida tempus sapien cursus. Pellentesque sapien nisl, rutrum ut commodo vel, finibus id sapien.</p>

Vestibulum velit purus, sollicitudin sit amet ultrices vel, ullamcorper sit amet erat. Suspendisse venenatis vestibulum suscipit. Suspendisse id feugiat purus, quis posuere leo. Aenean quis felis eleifend, pellentesque lacus eu, venenatis lorem. Nam sem ante, congue varius quam id, vehicula condimentum turpis. Aliquam mollis erat auctor quam interdum, et dictum orci laoreet. Morbi id odio ex. Suspendisse eget massa in diam pellentesque venenatis. Vivamus convallis sapien lacus, eu sagittis eros interdum quis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu euismod nisi. Pellentesque pellentesque tortor sed dui vehicula malesuada. Ut nec elementum dolor. Nunc vel arcu sed nibh consequat lobortis id facilisis lectus.</p>

<p>Donec condimentum, risus at luctus blandit, metus diam efficitur turpis, vitae mattis ipsum nisi eget arcu. Proin at sollicitudin purus. Integer vel arcu massa. Aenean eu massa orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec justo massa, ullamcorper in erat eget, vestibulum luctus nunc. Etiam ullamcorper eleifend nisi non laoreet. Proin porta porta nunc quis malesuada. Curabitur fringilla pellentesque neque. Pellentesque in laoreet justo. Sed vitae dolor imperdiet, feugiat magna a, hendrerit dui. Donec convallis sem quis interdum consectetur. Vivamus pellentesque tempor ultrices. Maecenas ultricies placerat tempor.</p>

<p>Ut non euismod orci. Cras et sem non tellus eleifend volutpat at quis tellus. Aliquam vel lacus tincidunt, condimentum lacus tristique, lacinia augue. Nulla dictum varius ante, vitae pretium eros hendrerit ac. Nam non rhoncus nisl. Mauris finibus blandit finibus. Suspendisse varius odio vitae velit tempus, et suscipit augue dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>

<p>Sed euismod id arcu vel posuere. Proin in purus gravida, convallis leo quis, sollicitudin arcu. In eu leo commodo, interdum est eget, lobortis nulla. Sed imperdiet finibus justo ac mollis. Quisque pellentesque risus quis nunc imperdiet tincidunt. Integer erat eros, mollis dignissim molestie a, efficitur quis eros. Vestibulum quam nulla, sodales ut ipsum id, tempus aliquet leo. Nulla commodo ornare libero, sit amet tincidunt orci viverra eget.</p>

Morbi consequat nibh magna, in pharetra ex ultricies eu. Nam sapien dui, commodo vitae lacinia vel, imperdiet ut dolor. Maecenas in augue tortor. Vestibulum semper at tellus non ullamcorper. Donec porttitor ligula vel metus malesuada, quis luctus erat aliquam. Quisque et suscipit diam, vel lacinia arcu. Maecenas quis tincidunt mi. Proin imperdiet scelerisque placerat. Sed vehicula, neque vel laoreet rhoncus, dolor erat aliquam velit, eu tristique nisl felis vitae est. Aliquam sagittis massa id risus facilisis, non efficitur mi bibendum. Phasellus sem leo, fringilla ac nunc non, euismod tristique urna. Praesent rhoncus turpis non elementum mattis.</p>

<p>Duis eu vulputate diam. Nulla eu justo et mauris sagittis bibendum. Aliquam enim tortor, tincidunt et orci vitae, pharetra pretium augue. Morbi mauris odio, auctor et lacus a, placerat facilisis tellus. Duis consectetur pellentesque neque et tincidunt. Integer at ex a eros consectetur feugiat. Nulla elit erat, euismod a mauris eget, accumsan fringilla sapien. Etiam augue lectus, ornare nec mi nec, sollicitudin fermentum libero.</p>

Sed auctor gravida posuere. Nullam a nulla eget tortor tempus feugiat sit amet vitae nulla. Phasellus consectetur eget ipsum quis volutpat. Nam bibendum sem diam, at vulputate sem hendrerit vel. Maecenas elementum egestas porttitor. Sed vitae pulvinar odio, id maximus nulla. Donec mattis tortor eu accumsan suscipit.

<p>Aenean interdum nisi dui, in egestas risus vulputate eget. Nullam justo lacus, imperdiet a nunc eget, pretium semper neque. Phasellus ut sollicitudin ex, a interdum magna. Nam posuere neque non massa cursus placerat. Praesent velit mi, congue at lorem sed, hendrerit viverra dui. Nam molestie ultrices tortor at vulputate. Cras ornare fermentum augue in vehicula. Duis et nibh vitae mauris convallis laoreet. Aliquam nec consectetur lacus. Nunc vestibulum nibh vitae nisl commodo, et pulvinar justo posuere. Aliquam sit amet velit non nulla vehicula porttitor. Morbi ut ipsum id eros aliquam vehicula id eget tellus.</p>

<p>Sed dictum venenatis lorem et rhoncus. Suspendisse commodo nibh quis est tristique pulvinar. Maecenas egestas, mi sed egestas accumsan, orci eros imperdiet est, in congue lectus turpis nec diam. Nullam urna turpis, molestie et magna quis, vehicula vehicula felis. Etiam est dolor, dictum eu sem id, placerat egestas tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris vitae mattis ante, vitae sodales neque. Sed quis mi eget felis scelerisque ornare. Integer sit amet nibh malesuada, bibendum dolor non, aliquet ante. Donec eget ultrices ipsum. Vivamus tincidunt turpis elit, scelerisque vulputate elit porttitor tincidunt. Phasellus dignissim est sem, pretium blandit libero lacinia eget. Proin quis eleifend turpis. Donec eu est nec nisi condimentum tristique sed quis mi. Vestibulum purus nibh, laoreet non elementum in, rhoncus sed dolor. Nullam eget neque sed mauris ullamcorper consequat eu vel nisl.</p>

<p>Ut consectetur ex ut lectus cursus, at rutrum mi cursus. Quisque sodales mauris et tellus rutrum, et mattis mauris pharetra. Aenean fringilla sem tellus, in egestas arcu vehicula quis. Vivamus ultrices, leo vel euismod consequat, velit lacus facilisis massa, sed malesuada nulla ante in ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam efficitur congue nibh. Quisque dignissim massa vel porta facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque eget lacus in dolor hendrerit congue sit amet quis urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque pellentesque, neque sit amet auctor lacinia, tellus arcu lobortis elit, in sagittis mi nisl at odio. Donec efficitur orci id neque hendrerit tristique. Fusce maximus at arcu vitae consectetur. Donec elementum, augue commodo posuere feugiat, diam turpis semper turpis, et pellentesque elit nunc id mi.</p>

<p>Cras at mauris sed nisl dignissim auctor non vel justo. Mauris ornare ligula malesuada justo mollis bibendum. Aliquam vel dui et justo porta finibus. Nam pulvinar dolor mi. Curabitur nec nibh sit amet mauris finibus mollis sit amet sed enim. Sed tincidunt, urna fermentum finibus vestibulum, nisi metus lacinia nisi, vitae dapibus velit enim et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris porta, eros at hendrerit tristique, eros ante lacinia risus, iaculis elementum diam diam nec diam. Aenean semper, orci eu placerat sagittis, nunc turpis finibus tortor, in dictum arcu erat sit amet sem. Curabitur eget urna in dui dignissim congue. Morbi at elit vel orci bibendum finibus. Curabitur sed tempor mi, et porta massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec vehicula ex vitae odio pulvinar, vel venenatis nunc ultricies. Fusce a rhoncus est. Morbi non lobortis orci, vitae sagittis urna. Curabitur dui est, consequat non lectus at, sollicitudin posuere odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Mauris eget euismod lorem. Nam in nisl arcu. Ut ultrices blandit turpis et commodo. Cras lectus ipsum, vestibulum vitae est quis, bibendum condimentum urna. Donec nec nunc at dui iaculis lobortis. Aenean feugiat tellus sed dictum fermentum. Donec iaculis enim et mattis feugiat. Cras ante lorem, gravida vestibulum sollicitudin quis, luctus at metus.</p>

<p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris sed mollis lacus. Nulla sodales efficitur tortor vel facilisis. Aliquam accumsan hendrerit quam pulvinar dapibus. Aenean ut magna dignissim, accumsan velit et, feugiat libero. Suspendisse ac sem nunc. Quisque tempus tortor eleifend ante congue, quis consectetur lorem bibendum. Curabitur congue nibh sollicitudin porttitor ornare. Sed tellus urna, molestie sed rutrum et, lobortis id tortor.</p>

<p>Ut nibh orci, blandit ut ex nec, volutpat volutpat lectus. Ut hendrerit ac dolor quis porttitor. Suspendisse dui orci, rutrum id consequat vehicula, elementum placerat tellus. Mauris interdum quam sed nulla commodo malesuada. Integer lacinia egestas nibh, ullamcorper porttitor velit viverra non. Quisque eget velit a ipsum tempus molestie non ut lorem. Integer dapibus aliquam volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla at dui et ipsum cursus placerat. Mauris dignissim mi non purus luctus, non convallis dolor lacinia. Aenean sed congue erat. Maecenas viverra metus turpis, ac commodo lacus maximus a. Donec ut ornare libero, ac molestie arcu. Nullam mi urna, molestie quis magna at, cursus cursus enim.</p>

<p>Nunc posuere erat vel elit hendrerit hendrerit. In interdum risus at aliquam facilisis. Nullam auctor hendrerit accumsan. Nunc facilisis tellus sem, at vehicula velit vehicula maximus. Phasellus finibus tincidunt purus eget vehicula. Nulla facilisi. In iaculis ultrices erat sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam rutrum vitae libero ac congue. Nullam eget consequat mauris. Nulla congue enim et lectus sollicitudin auctor quis sed ligula. Morbi nec tincidunt nisl. Aenean a augue vel nisl lobortis commodo. Proin tincidunt at sapien sed molestie. Sed et volutpat enim. Mauris imperdiet magna non neque tristique, in tincidunt lacus sagittis. Proin vulputate metus ex, id pretium ante eleifend nec.</p>
</div>

<div class="print-footer"><img src="http://placehold.it/1120x200" /><div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simply use Max-height, and overflow scroll. But remember to give them inner so you can control the height of the content**

```css
    .print-footer {
      display:none;
      width:100%;
      position:fixed;
      bottom:0;
    }
     .print-footer img {
      max-width:100%;
     }

      .article-content {
        height:100%;
      overflow:hidden;
       }

  .article-inner{
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
      .print-footer {
        display:block;
       }
```

```html
<div class="article-content">
<div class="article-inner">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae posuere felis. Fusce euismod quam sit amet sodales maximus. Cras eget scelerisque augue. Proin a tincidunt nisl, vitae lacinia lectus. Vivamus tincidunt felis eget facilisis tristique. Nullam facilisis, eros quis hendrerit hendrerit, purus nisi congue libero, sit amet facilisis ligula sapien sit amet augue. Integer ac nulla nisl. Suspendisse sed eros quis est interdum ultricies. Donec tincidunt libero lacus, sed laoreet quam rutrum eget. Morbi vitae ullamcorper erat. Phasellus eu purus eget ante congue blandit ac ac ipsum.</p>

<p>Mauris neque ligula, dictum a nibh ut, volutpat ullamcorper urna. In ullamcorper tortor sit amet pellentesque iaculis. Mauris sagittis eleifend scelerisque. Vestibulum volutpat euismod turpis, gravida tempus liguala ultricies vulputate. Maecenas odio sem, pulvinar eget vulputate nec, dictum mollis neque. Aliquam porttitor mi eu scelerisque varius. Etiam vel eros mattis, luctus diam ac, pretium ligula. Maecenas placerat posuere turpis, id convallis augue efficitur porttitor. Fusce tempor tempor convallis.</p>

Quisque imperdiet a dui sed maximus. Nulla sollicitudin fermentum est nec interdum. Nulla consectetur tempus purus, id lobortis neque molestie elementum. Praesent pharetra convallis tincidunt. Proin pellentesque placerat libero vitae pretium. Aenean sodales fringilla ipsum, id suscipit leo. Aliquam sit amet ornare nulla. Quisque sem nisi, auctor facilisis arcu varius, tristique maximus ligula. Nulla imperdiet nunc ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque magna lacus, elementum non sem eget, posuere blandit nunc. Morbi nec arcu vitae odio consequat consectetur. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

<p>Nulla facilisi. Duis pretium blandit elit, a facilisis ipsum finibus sed. Pellentesque semper molestie consectetur. Vivamus sit amet enim ac quam commodo vulputate a pretium nibh. Sed commodo posuere metus, nec mattis arcu lobortis vel. Praesent finibus maximus vestibulum. Sed ultrices urna et pulvinar elementum. Pellentesque lacinia lorem sit amet lectus tempus, ut pharetra nisi tincidunt. Ut sit amet convallis odio. Nam ut massa nisi. Donec ac laoreet mi. Duis quis elementum sapien, at tempor odio. Sed tempus urna ac venenatis commodo. Suspendisse bibendum tortor sit amet risus convallis, gravida tempus sapien cursus. Pellentesque sapien nisl, rutrum ut commodo vel, finibus id sapien.</p>

Vestibulum velit purus, sollicitudin sit amet ultrices vel, ullamcorper sit amet erat. Suspendisse venenatis vestibulum suscipit. Suspendisse id feugiat purus, quis posuere leo. Aenean quis felis eleifend, pellentesque lacus eu, venenatis lorem. Nam sem ante, congue varius quam id, vehicula condimentum turpis. Aliquam mollis erat auctor quam interdum, et dictum orci laoreet. Morbi id odio ex. Suspendisse eget massa in diam pellentesque venenatis. Vivamus convallis sapien lacus, eu sagittis eros interdum quis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu euismod nisi. Pellentesque pellentesque tortor sed dui vehicula malesuada. Ut nec elementum dolor. Nunc vel arcu sed nibh consequat lobortis id facilisis lectus.</p>

<p>Donec condimentum, risus at luctus blandit, metus diam efficitur turpis, vitae mattis ipsum nisi eget arcu. Proin at sollicitudin purus. Integer vel arcu massa. Aenean eu massa orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec justo massa, ullamcorper in erat eget, vestibulum luctus nunc. Etiam ullamcorper eleifend nisi non laoreet. Proin porta porta nunc quis malesuada. Curabitur fringilla pellentesque neque. Pellentesque in laoreet justo. Sed vitae dolor imperdiet, feugiat magna a, hendrerit dui. Donec convallis sem quis interdum consectetur. Vivamus pellentesque tempor ultrices. Maecenas ultricies placerat tempor.</p>

<p>Ut non euismod orci. Cras et sem non tellus eleifend volutpat at quis tellus. Aliquam vel lacus tincidunt, condimentum lacus tristique, lacinia augue. Nulla dictum varius ante, vitae pretium eros hendrerit ac. Nam non rhoncus nisl. Mauris finibus blandit finibus. Suspendisse varius odio vitae velit tempus, et suscipit augue dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>

<p>Sed euismod id arcu vel posuere. Proin in purus gravida, convallis leo quis, sollicitudin arcu. In eu leo commodo, interdum est eget, lobortis nulla. Sed imperdiet finibus justo ac mollis. Quisque pellentesque risus quis nunc imperdiet tincidunt. Integer erat eros, mollis dignissim molestie a, efficitur quis eros. Vestibulum quam nulla, sodales ut ipsum id, tempus aliquet leo. Nulla commodo ornare libero, sit amet tincidunt orci viverra eget.</p>

Morbi consequat nibh magna, in pharetra ex ultricies eu. Nam sapien dui, commodo vitae lacinia vel, imperdiet ut dolor. Maecenas in augue tortor. Vestibulum semper at tellus non ullamcorper. Donec porttitor ligula vel metus malesuada, quis luctus erat aliquam. Quisque et suscipit diam, vel lacinia arcu. Maecenas quis tincidunt mi. Proin imperdiet scelerisque placerat. Sed vehicula, neque vel laoreet rhoncus, dolor erat aliquam velit, eu tristique nisl felis vitae est. Aliquam sagittis massa id risus facilisis, non efficitur mi bibendum. Phasellus sem leo, fringilla ac nunc non, euismod tristique urna. Praesent rhoncus turpis non elementum mattis.</p>

<p>Duis eu vulputate diam. Nulla eu justo et mauris sagittis bibendum. Aliquam enim tortor, tincidunt et orci vitae, pharetra pretium augue. Morbi mauris odio, auctor et lacus a, placerat facilisis tellus. Duis consectetur pellentesque neque et tincidunt. Integer at ex a eros consectetur feugiat. Nulla elit erat, euismod a mauris eget, accumsan fringilla sapien. Etiam augue lectus, ornare nec mi nec, sollicitudin fermentum libero.</p>

Sed auctor gravida posuere. Nullam a nulla eget tortor tempus feugiat sit amet vitae nulla. Phasellus consectetur eget ipsum quis volutpat. Nam bibendum sem diam, at vulputate sem hendrerit vel. Maecenas elementum egestas porttitor. Sed vitae pulvinar odio, id maximus nulla. Donec mattis tortor eu accumsan suscipit.

<p>Aenean interdum nisi dui, in egestas risus vulputate eget. Nullam justo lacus, imperdiet a nunc eget, pretium semper neque. Phasellus ut sollicitudin ex, a interdum magna. Nam posuere neque non massa cursus placerat. Praesent velit mi, congue at lorem sed, hendrerit viverra dui. Nam molestie ultrices tortor at vulputate. Cras ornare fermentum augue in vehicula. Duis et nibh vitae mauris convallis laoreet. Aliquam nec consectetur lacus. Nunc vestibulum nibh vitae nisl commodo, et pulvinar justo posuere. Aliquam sit amet velit non nulla vehicula porttitor. Morbi ut ipsum id eros aliquam vehicula id eget tellus.</p>

<p>Sed dictum venenatis lorem et rhoncus. Suspendisse commodo nibh quis est tristique pulvinar. Maecenas egestas, mi sed egestas accumsan, orci eros imperdiet est, in congue lectus turpis nec diam. Nullam urna turpis, molestie et magna quis, vehicula vehicula felis. Etiam est dolor, dictum eu sem id, placerat egestas tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris vitae mattis ante, vitae sodales neque. Sed quis mi eget felis scelerisque ornare. Integer sit amet nibh malesuada, bibendum dolor non, aliquet ante. Donec eget ultrices ipsum. Vivamus tincidunt turpis elit, scelerisque vulputate elit porttitor tincidunt. Phasellus dignissim est sem, pretium blandit libero lacinia eget. Proin quis eleifend turpis. Donec eu est nec nisi condimentum tristique sed quis mi. Vestibulum purus nibh, laoreet non elementum in, rhoncus sed dolor. Nullam eget neque sed mauris ullamcorper consequat eu vel nisl.</p>

<p>Ut consectetur ex ut lectus cursus, at rutrum mi cursus. Quisque sodales mauris et tellus rutrum, et mattis mauris pharetra. Aenean fringilla sem tellus, in egestas arcu vehicula quis. Vivamus ultrices, leo vel euismod consequat, velit lacus facilisis massa, sed malesuada nulla ante in ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam efficitur congue nibh. Quisque dignissim massa vel porta facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque eget lacus in dolor hendrerit congue sit amet quis urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque pellentesque, neque sit amet auctor lacinia, tellus arcu lobortis elit, in sagittis mi nisl at odio. Donec efficitur orci id neque hendrerit tristique. Fusce maximus at arcu vitae consectetur. Donec elementum, augue commodo posuere feugiat, diam turpis semper turpis, et pellentesque elit nunc id mi.</p>

<p>Cras at mauris sed nisl dignissim auctor non vel justo. Mauris ornare ligula malesuada justo mollis bibendum. Aliquam vel dui et justo porta finibus. Nam pulvinar dolor mi. Curabitur nec nibh sit amet mauris finibus mollis sit amet sed enim. Sed tincidunt, urna fermentum finibus vestibulum, nisi metus lacinia nisi, vitae dapibus velit enim et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris porta, eros at hendrerit tristique, eros ante lacinia risus, iaculis elementum diam diam nec diam. Aenean semper, orci eu placerat sagittis, nunc turpis finibus tortor, in dictum arcu erat sit amet sem. Curabitur eget urna in dui dignissim congue. Morbi at elit vel orci bibendum finibus. Curabitur sed tempor mi, et porta massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec vehicula ex vitae odio pulvinar, vel venenatis nunc ultricies. Fusce a rhoncus est. Morbi non lobortis orci, vitae sagittis urna. Curabitur dui est, consequat non lectus at, sollicitudin posuere odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Mauris eget euismod lorem. Nam in nisl arcu. Ut ultrices blandit turpis et commodo. Cras lectus ipsum, vestibulum vitae est quis, bibendum condimentum urna. Donec nec nunc at dui iaculis lobortis. Aenean feugiat tellus sed dictum fermentum. Donec iaculis enim et mattis feugiat. Cras ante lorem, gravida vestibulum sollicitudin quis, luctus at metus.</p>

<p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris sed mollis lacus. Nulla sodales efficitur tortor vel facilisis. Aliquam accumsan hendrerit quam pulvinar dapibus. Aenean ut magna dignissim, accumsan velit et, feugiat libero. Suspendisse ac sem nunc. Quisque tempus tortor eleifend ante congue, quis consectetur lorem bibendum. Curabitur congue nibh sollicitudin porttitor ornare. Sed tellus urna, molestie sed rutrum et, lobortis id tortor.</p>

<p>Ut nibh orci, blandit ut ex nec, volutpat volutpat lectus. Ut hendrerit ac dolor quis porttitor. Suspendisse dui orci, rutrum id consequat vehicula, elementum placerat tellus. Mauris interdum quam sed nulla commodo malesuada. Integer lacinia egestas nibh, ullamcorper porttitor velit viverra non. Quisque eget velit a ipsum tempus molestie non ut lorem. Integer dapibus aliquam volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla at dui et ipsum cursus placerat. Mauris dignissim mi non purus luctus, non convallis dolor lacinia. Aenean sed congue erat. Maecenas viverra metus turpis, ac commodo lacus maximus a. Donec ut ornare libero, ac molestie arcu. Nullam mi urna, molestie quis magna at, cursus cursus enim.</p>

<p>Nunc posuere erat vel elit hendrerit hendrerit. In interdum risus at aliquam facilisis. Nullam auctor hendrerit accumsan. Nunc facilisis tellus sem, at vehicula velit vehicula maximus. Phasellus finibus tincidunt purus eget vehicula. Nulla facilisi. In iaculis ultrices erat sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam rutrum vitae libero ac congue. Nullam eget consequat mauris. Nulla congue enim et lectus sollicitudin auctor quis sed ligula. Morbi nec tincidunt nisl. Aenean a augue vel nisl lobortis commodo. Proin tincidunt at sapien sed molestie. Sed et volutpat enim. Mauris imperdiet magna non neque tristique, in tincidunt lacus sagittis. Proin vulputate metus ex, id pretium ante eleifend nec.</p>
</div></div>

<div class="print-footer"><img src="http://placehold.it/1120x200" /><div>
```